# Broadcast receiver issue while navigating to another screen

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have used broadcast receiver to open up an activity A every time call ends.
The activity redirects to another activity B after 5 seconds.

Now when another time call ends in spite of calling Activity A Broadcast receiver directly calls Activity B.

This is my code.

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
            savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
        } else {
            String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            int state = 0;
            if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                switch (state) {
                    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:

                        intent = new Intent(context, Create_log.class);
                        System.out.println("call state called");
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            } else if (stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
            }

            onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This takes to create_log.class and in create_log i have called another class after 5 seconds.

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Create_log.this, Home_nav.class);
            Create_log.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            Create_log.this.finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

The code redirects directly to class B and class A is skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Once try with this line in your Intent of your onRecvie() method

Comment: Actually it comes all of a sudden and not everytime. So i am unable to make sure if it would work successfully. Anyways up till now it is working fine so upvoting your answer.